# Not able to Query The AccountTeamMembers

Tags: apex, soql, community

I have written a query  for our customer portal.where the contact is logged in and he should be able see the AccoutTeams for the Account to which belongs to.

I am Querying the Account Id to pass it to the AccoutTeamMember Object using  "user.contact.AccountId"

Query:

```
accTeam = [
    SELECT Account.Name, AccountId, Account.Account_Number__c, AccountAccessLevel,
    TeamMemberRole, UserId
    from AccountTeamMember where AccountId = :user.Contact.AccountId
];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_accountteammember.htm) clearly states Customer Portal Users can't access this Object.

> **Special Access Rules**
>
> 1. This object is available only for Enterprise, Unlimited, and
>      Performance Edition users who have enabled the account team
>      functionality.
> 2. Customer Portal users can't access this object.

One workaround you can try is make the apex class as `without sharing` keyword so that the query runs in system mode not in user mode to surpass this limitation.

Hope is helps.

Comment: Hi Vignesh. Thanks for letting me know that AccoutTeamMember cannot be accessed by the Portal users .I have used the keyword "without sharing" for my class .But still the result of the query is not displayed.